# HashMap to json performance impact

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch, jackson

I have to index some business data into ElasticSearch. For that , I am
storing data in HashMap and then converting it to Json using Jackson
library.

My concern is related to performance impact of `HashMap` vs POJO object to `Json`.
Should I store data in some POJO bean and then convert it to `Json` or storing it in `HashMap` and converting to `Json` is fine?

PS: Assume data is key-value(String-String) so i am using `HashMap<String,String>`

Comment: "I am storing data in HashMap and then converting it to Json using Jackson library" - If you already do that: Do you have any performance issues with your implementation?

Comment: Why do you want to have a Pojo if your  Pojo only contains a HashMap ?

Comment: If you are concerned about performance then why don't you convert hashmap to json by yourself...?

Comment: @jeanr POJO does not contains HashMap. My point was related to something like this. SampleClass{ String Type; String Name;} or HashMap having Type, and Name as Key. Is Jackson required to do some extra things while converting HashMap(with some data) ? which will not be case in POJO?

Comment: FYI @all I just did testing and found performance was 800 millisec slower in case of HashMap. And that also with 4 key-value pairs.